# How can I override the Angular Material Purple?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to use the deeppurple-amber.css for Angular 2 Material, but instead of the deeppurple I want to overide that color with a different color, everything else should be exactly the same though. How best to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular provides these pre-built themes

- deeppurple-amber.css
- indigo-pink.css
- pink-bluegrey.css
- purple-green.css

so if you are looking for any color which is listed in this then u may put it straight away by referencing the file directly.

but if not then u may have to build a **custom theme** this way [link](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)

[I tried changing colors in pre-built themes directly in the file , doesnt work . so create a theme file referencing the deeppurple file then add a new entry to your styles]